# Default references will only be applied in edit mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

It's been a long time since I did something in unity3d but today I opened an old project of mine to build an apk-file from a game I did about a year ago. But as soon as I had opened the project I saw that every reference in my c# scripts were set to *None*. I can't change them back and my project doesn't work without them. Below that there is an info box which says "Default references will only be applied in edit mode". I really don't know what to do because, like I already said, I didn't worked with unity for a year and I'm not so familiar with all the things. To show you what I mean I added a screenshot below.

It would be awesome if anyone could help me. Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot from the reference section in the Inspector of a c# script in Unity3d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF5iZ.png)

Comment: select the gameobject with that script in the scene/hierarchy, not in your assets/scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the problem get fixed if you open your project with the same version of unity you've been working with a year ago maybe earlier. At this point the damage might already be done, but do you have a back-up for your project? You can  start over with that earlier unity version, it will work if you haven't work with it since.

Comment: Do you know, how I can find out which version I used back then?

Answer (score 0):

I am considering this only a message, or hint. Once you run the application, the references are getting assigned in the inspector automatically. They even stay when stopping the application, but not after saving or after relaunching unity. Weird behavior.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.